# Extracting data from piped string KDB

Tags: kdb

I have the below table

```
t:flip (`comps`uid)!(("ub01,140,16600,1|msil,140,31,0|gsc,140,40,0|csf,140,9,1|ci,140,18,1|in,140,10,1|j106,100,100,1";"ub01,140,16600,1|msil,140,31,0|gsc,140,40,0|csf,140,9,1|ci,140,18,1|in,140,10,1|j106,100,100,1");`user1`user2)
```

I am trying to populate the `valueWhere1` and `valueWhere0` columns from the below table

```
tRes:flip (`comps`uid`valueWhere1`valueWhere0)!(("ub01,140,16600,1|msil,140,31,0|gsc,140,40,0|csf,140,9,1|ci,140,18,1|in,140,10,1|j106,100,100,1";"ub01,140,16600,1|msil,140,31,0|gsc,140,40,0|csf,140,9,1|ci,140,18,1|in,140,10,1|j106,100,100,1");`user1`user2;(`ub01`csf`ci`in`j106;`ub01`csf`ci`in`j106);(`msil`gsc;`msil`gsc))
```

I have got the count of each string where the value before each pipe is either 1,0

```
t:update countWhere1:sum each {"1"=last x}''["|"vs'comps],countWhere0:sum each {"0"=last x}''["|"vs'comps] from t
```

Trying to pull in the first section of each string and filter based on the 1;0 flag. I have the below but not quite working

```
`$first each raze {"," vs x} each '{"|"vs x} each ("ub01,140,16600,1|msil,140,31,0|gsc,140,40,0|csf,140,9,1|ci,140,18,1|in,140,10,1|j106,100,100,1";"ub01,140,16600,1|msil,140,31,0|gsc,140,40,0|csf,140,9,1|ci,140,18,1|in,140,10,1|j106,100,100,1")
```

Thanks for looking

Comment: could you provide your expected output? struggling to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: actually I think I see what you want

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `"|"` separation similar to Matt and then using `0:` to parse based on the assumption that your bit between the pipes is predictable and regular:

```
t,'exec{group`$"valueWhere",/:string(!).("S  B";csv)0:"|"vs x}each comps from t
```

Note that this may need a bit of tweaking to generalise ... the dictionaries created after the group may not always conform, in which case you may need to

```
t,'exec{`valueWhere1`valueWhere0#group`$"valueWhere",/:string(!).("S  B";csv)0:"|"vs x}each comps from t
```

Answer (score 0):

This will seperate each comps by `"|"`, then the nested function will filter based on the last character of each string in the list. You can either convert directly to boolean `"B"$` if it's always 1 or 0.

```
select {x where "B"$-1#/: x} each "|" vs/: comps from t
```

or convert to an `int` with `=` in the `where`

```
select {x where 1 = "I"$-1#/: x} each "|" vs/: comps from t
```